Is it essential that a Sofer (and not a layman) check one's Tefilin?
A rabbi told me to check my tefilin myself if for any reason I can’t reach a sofer.
Can I check them myself and if so what are the most important halochos for me to know?

Welcome to MiYodeya Moshe and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

I can't imagine why one would need to be a sofer. Anyone who knows what to look for should be able to.

@DoubleAA I think "sofer" here is used in the sense of "expert checker" as opposed to a literal scribe. I'm not sure what qualifies one as an expert for the purpose of checking tefillin; maybe a layman well-versed in the relevant halacha is an expert by definition. In any case, I'd be more worried about them messing up the reassembly than overlooking a pesul.

@shmosel seems like a pointless tautology then.

@DoubleAA Very possibly.

@shmosel then why assume that's what he meant? Better to assume the question isn't tautological

If you know how to open them up and then re-seal them without damaging them (watching a sofer drill into my tefilin to open them up was a little scary, but I trusted he know what he was doing), and you know all the halachos of what's required, then someone who happens to have horrible penmanship could still do this. If I'm not mistaken, the YU safrus class is just the halacha. You have to sit down on your own and build up the calligraphy.
